# How to change string display order?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I make the call, I only get an aldo of the type "2022-10-12" I need it to be "12/10/2022". I've tried to format the date but it's an Edm.LocalDateTime, which comes from SAP. Would you be able to format the string and reorder?

my code:

```
 val textoData = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texto_data_abastecimento)
        textoData.text = abastecimento.datam!!.date.toString()
```

I've tried and it didn't work:

```
 val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(supply.datam!!.date.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: have you tried using pattern "yyyy-dd-MM" in your LocalDateTime.parse() function?